# Need ActiveRecord query to find parent that has specific child record along with others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm using Ruby on Rails and Postgres and I have three tables: Event, Speaker, and Event_Speaker (the last of which enables a two-way `has_many, through` relationship between Event and Speaker).

On an individual speaker's `show` view, I'm trying to display not only all of the events featuring that speaker, but also the count of how many events feature only that speaker (versus events featuring that speaker along with one or more others).

I can't seem to come up with an ActiveRecord query that is able to accomplish this latter part. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't see why you need the join table event_speaker (the correct name would be events_speakers). Can't you just make: Event :has_many => speakers. And if there is a main speaker, you can add to Event :has_one => :main_speaker, :as => Speaker, :foreign_key => :main_speaker_id ?

Comment: @MauricioMoraes because a speaker can speak at multiple events presumably

Comment: can we do a count on number of speakers at one event, and choose the one only has 1 from the chosen speaker's events?

Comment: @MauricioMoraes: j-dexx is correct here -- I have a group of speakers that speak at multiple events, sometimes together at the same ones.

Lusketeer: That's essentially what I'm getting at but I'm not sure which query to use.

Comment: I got it now. Well, in that case, I think it'll be a tough query, both for performance and for understanding. I suggest you cache the speaker_count on the event and look for the speaker's events where the speaker_count is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to give an answer based on Mauricio Moraes' comment.

Migration

```
def change
  add_column :events, :speakers_count, :integer, default: 0
end
```

Model

```
class EventSpeaker
  belongs_to :event, counter_cache: :speakers_count
  belongs_to :speaker
end
```

So now you can do a simple query

```
speaker = Speaker.first
only_speaker_events = speaker.events.where(speakers_count: 1)
```

Comment: On terms of seeding the data you might want to check [this](http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2016/02/05/proper-counter-cache-migrations-in-rails/)

Answer (score 1):

What about using `select`. Load all events for the speaker from the database and then reject any which have more than one speaker.

```
speaker.events.select { |e| e.speakers.count == 1 }
```

Comment: It seems a bit silly to load 1,000 records if you're only going to keep 10.

Comment: Thank you! I accepted the other answers as it accounts for performance issues, but this one is certainly simple and to the point. Appreciated!

Comment: > It seems a bit silly to load 1,000 records if you're only going to keep 10.
Indeed.